# Can I get Google Chrome to spell check correctly?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

While typing in a text box in Google Chrome I can usually see which words I have spelt incorrectly as they are underlined by a wavy red line. If I right click I am then offered alternate spellings or I can 'Add to dictionary'.

This has stopped working on my home PC so every word is now highlighted. How can I correct this?

Comment: Check **Options > Under the Bonnet > Change Font... > Languages** anything look off to you?

Comment: Looks normal to me, I have 'English (United Kingdom)' selected as both Spell checker language and Google Chrome language. Same settings as my laptop which works fine.

Comment: Any extensions installed?

Comment: No extensions, think I have found a solution, will post details later today when I can get back on the PC that is having the problem to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by my web filtering software blocking the download of the dictionary file. When I opened it in a text editor (notepad++ in this case) I saw an html page with the title:

> K9 Web Protection Alert: Category Blocked

The dictionary file is found at:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\Dictionaries
```

Removing the file and unblocking software downloads allowed Chrome to re-download the dictionary file and spell check works again.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the fonts and language to English (United Kingdom) for spell check and google chrome display. Works like a charm :)