# Why is Chrome incorrectly underlining correctly spelled words?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spell-check, brave

Chrome (and derivative browsers such as Brave) quite often don't recognize common words and underline them with red. When I right-click, no suggestions are offered other than to add it to the dictionary.

It's intermittent, with often only a single instance of the word being highlighted while others in the same sentence aren't. It's usually small words like "to", "the", "there", etc.

Is this a known problem?

I'm using macOS and Brave 1.34.81 built on Chromium 97.0.4692.99. Although I've had the issue for many years, on older versions of macOS, and on vanilla Chrome as well as Brave.

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: The spellcheck routines have been poor on things like `their they're there` for several years now. I see things aren't improving much:\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get Google Chrome to spell check correctly?](https://superuser.com/questions/160288/can-i-get-google-chrome-to-spell-check-correctly)

Comment: Very similar Q (with comments but not answers) -> https://superuser.com/q/1673791/152004

Comment: You could install a third-party tool (e.g. [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/)) and see if that does a better job.